# boost::flyweight as value in std::map

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary, insert

I am wondering why `std::map` does not replace value after using insert.
example:

```
using std::string;
using boost::flyweight;
using std::map;
int main() 
{ 
    map<string,flyweight<string>> testMap;

    flyweight<string> str("1");
    testMap.insert(std::make_pair("1","1"));
    testMap.insert(std::make_pair("1","2"));
    str = "2";
    printf("Inside map at \"1\" is:%s\r\n",testMap.at("1").get().c_str());
    printf("str equals %s",str.get().c_str());
}
```

Will print:

`Inside map at "1" is: 1`

`str equals 2`

used `flyweight<string>` just as a example, same thing happens when using `int`s.

Working on windows OS,  visual 2010 ide.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( const value_type& value );` of `std::map`

won't insert element if it already exists

Here `pair::second` element in the pair is set to true if a new element was inserted or false if an equivalent key already existed.

Your question has nothing to do with `boost`

Check the example on [**this**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/) page. It illustrates your scenario.

Comment: uh.. thanks P0W. that was bad on my side I was sure of the opposite, should've checked that before.  
testMap["1"] = flyweight<string>("2");
fixes things.

Comment: @AleksanderFular yes operator `[]` would update the key's value, however, point to note that it'd insert new key, if it's not already present